# Overwrote Windows bootloader with Mint: how to restore?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, windows, grub

I have encountered serious problem while experimenting with Ubuntu/Mint. A few days ago I felt like trying Linux. I had Windows 7 installed on my SSD drive. Since I had one free HDD I decided to install Ubuntu there and Ubuntu boot overwrote my standard Windows boot loader, so I had to select the booting drive each time starting my computer (from BIOS <kbd>F12</kbd> button).

After a few days, I decided to try Mint since Ubuntu didnt feel good to me. I have installed Mint, on the same partition as Windows (on the SSD) and removed the Ubuntu ext4 partitions from the Windows hard drive manager.

Now, each time I try to boot my computer from any drive I have installed I'm getting the message from GRUB "no such device [number]".

I am unable to run Windows 7 due to the error mentioned above.

I am not able to run Linux Mint due to the error that system cannot find system file source.

I would really like to restore my Windows files. Please keep in mind, that only tool I have to use right now is a live Mint USB drive.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://askubuntu.com/questions/541645/is-there-anyway-i-cant-restor-my-system-from-this-point

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a windows question than an unix one, but heres how you can recover the windows bootloader:

Boot into a Windows 7 install or recovery disk. You should be able to find a recovery iso online or on the Microsoft website. Once in, open up a command prompt and run the following:

bootrec.exe /fixmbr

This will reinstall the Windows bootloader, and replace the Linux Mint one.

If you would like to just get access to the files on your Windows partition, you can search online for how to mount an ntfs partition in Linux Mint. That will let you copy or backup those files.